# prevent decreasing video quality in twilio

Tags: twilio

twillio video quality (resolution, height/width of video) decrease while connecting and never  improved.

Test condition

```
device: pc and mobile app
mobile send video and pc receive
connecting several minutes without idle mode.
sometimes move mobile
network condition: stable in office
```

Result

```
 video quality become worse by decreasing height and width of video
```

[image]
you can see that frame width and fram height has become smaller while frame rate is the same
in our condition, network is stable and does not have reason to decrease.
if it decrease worse, I would like it improve once condition become better.

Also, if the condition become worse, it is better to decrease frame rate rather than resolution of video.

How can I configure in that way?

Current implementation with Flutter

```
    final connectOptions = ConnectOptions(
      token,
      roomName: _channelName,
      preferredAudioCodecs: [OpusCodec()],
      audioTracks: [LocalAudioTrack(true)],
      dataTracks: [LocalDataTrack()],
      videoTracks: [LocalVideoTrack(true, _cameraCapturer)],
      enableNetworkQuality: true,
      networkQualityConfiguration: NetworkQualityConfiguration(
        remote: NetworkQualityVerbosity.NETWORK_QUALITY_VERBOSITY_MINIMAL,
      ),
      enableDominantSpeaker: true,
    );
    
    _room = await TwilioProgrammableVideo.connect(connectOptions);
```

Comment: Can you share the code/connection settings that you are using? Have you read this [guide on the recommended settings for video calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/developing-high-quality-video-applications)?

Comment: @philnash thank you for your reply. I have added code.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

> Also, if the condition become worse, it is better to decrease frame rate rather than resolution of video.

This is not necessarily true. From the [Twilio docs on developing high quality video applications](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/developing-high-quality-video-applications#general-recommendations):

> Frame-rate and resolution are the two main capture constraints that affect video fidelity. When the video source is a camera showing people or moving objects, typically the perceptual quality is better at higher frame-rate. However, for screen-sharing, the resolution is typically more relevant.

To my knowledge, if a network connection is able to support higher resolution video, then WebRTC and Twilio Video will send the resolution that can be supported. However, network connection is not the only variable when it comes to the resolution, CPU usage is also a factor, and matters particularly on mobile devices. Continuing from the docs:

> You should try to set resolution and frame-rate to the minimum value required by your use-case. Over-dimensioning resolution and frame-rate will have a negative impact on the CPU and network consumption and may increase latency. In addition, remember that the resolution and frame-rate you specify as capture constraints are just hints for the client video engine. The actual resolution and frame-rate may decrease if CPU overuse is detected or if the network capacity is not enough for the required traffic.

I see you have included the network quality API in your code. I'd recommend taking readings from that, as well as investigating [CPU profiling](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/cpu-profiler) in your application to see if you can get the resolution stable on your device.